# PHP fastcgi returns 403 on Lighttpd server

Tags: php, fastcgi, lighttpd, mod-fastcgi

I've been agonizing over this issue for the past day now. I've setup lighty on my server and it serves static files fine but keeps giving me 403 on php files.

I've gone through every tutorial, wiki and forum that I can find on the subject and nothing helped.

I've chown lighttpd:lighttpd the php files and chmod to 644 and 755. I really need some help here.

Here is a link to my *.conf files:

http://174.122.151.65/lighttpd/

BTW, I'm running on a centOS box.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the fastcgi.server section of your lighttpd.conf file

```
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" =>
    ( "localhost" =>
         (
            "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/php-fastcgi.socket",
            "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi"
         )
     )
 )
```

Comment: that's setup in the fastcgi.conf.

Is it supposed to be in the lighttpd.conf file too?

Comment: Don't know for sure.  The examples I found all had it in the base config file.  Couldn't hurt to try :)

Comment: I had the same thing and it turned out to be selinux. Curse you, selinux!

Answer (score 0):

If that doesn't work, try:

```
sudo lighty-enable-mod fastcgi 
sudo lighty-enable-mod fastcgi-php
```

Worked for me.